# Java Package Execution

Tags: java, directory, package

Here's my Situation:
I have a folder Structure:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\JavaTraining\Chapter3\examples.
```

examples is also a folder. Now, I have a file name `Calculator.Java` in Chapter3 folder with the package statement `package Chapter3;`. So, from the Command Line I compiled the file from the `JavaTraining` directory as `javac Chapter3\Calculator.java`, It compiled and I see a file `Calculator.class` generated. But when I run the command `java Chapter3.Calculator` from the `JavaTraining` Directory. It throwed me an `error: Could not find file or load main class Chapter3.Calculator`.

Then, I created a sub folder in `Chapter3` named `examples` and copied the `Calculator.java` into the examples folder and tried compiling and executing the file thinking Chapter3 as the root folder ( executed commands from the Chapter3 directory). No error, the file got executed.

Please can anyone explain me why this happened or what is the reason behind it, I am going mad...

`Calculator.java` is just a class Calculator with main function trying to find a sum from a printsum function of two variables.

I went through the suggestions provided in `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean`
According to the above, it was either the syntax mistake ( the way of trying to executing the file) or setting the `PATH and CLASSPATH` environment variables.

I even tried the `echo %CLASSPATH%` to see if my `CLASSPATH` variable is set to current directory. It did show me the `.` when I executed the echo command from `JavaTraining` directory. 
The file did not execute when I tried Chapter3 folder as root directory, but when I create a subfolder in Chapter3 and made Chapter3 as the root directory, it executed, what might be the reason or what am I doing wrong,

Here is the command line with the output:

```
C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\JavaTraining>javac Chapter3\Calculator.java

C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\JavaTraining>java Chapter3.Calculator
Error: Could not find or load main class Chapter3.Calculator

C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\JavaTraining>cd Chapter3

C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\JavaTraining\Chapter3>javac examples\Calculator.java

C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\JavaTraining\Chapter3>java examples.Calculator
The sum is 30

C:\Users\vikas\Desktop\JavaTraining\Chapter3>
```

The Calculator.java file:

```
// One Package Statement
package chapter3;
// The file in Chapter 3 folder, file in example folder has
//package examples;
// One or more import statements
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

// Class Declaration
public class Calculator {

    // State. Variables and Constants
    int i=10;
    long k = 20;

    // Behavior, one or more methods
     void printSum(){
         long sum;
         sum = i+ k;
    System.out.println("The sum is " + (i+k));
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Calculator c = new Calculator();
    c.printSum();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is calculator in a package?

Comment: The classpath has to be set to the top of the package hierarchy. If it's set to `.` then you should invoke java from there or set a classpath with the flag `cp`

Comment: from package JavaTraining, should be able to do both:
javac Chapter3\Calculator.java and 
java  Chapter3\Calculator

Comment: @LeTex: I thought so, but it didn't work

Comment: @pvg: the classpath is set to ' . ', can you please elaborate on what you mean

Comment: I think you are in  folder JavaTraining and trying to do java Calculator , try doing Java Chapter3\Calculator instead

Comment: @LeTex: I did java Chapter3.Calculator

Comment: access the class file using  / or \ depending on your OS

Comment: The top of your .java file should say the package you need to be in. That is essential for running a java program.

Comment: Can you actually show your code? Or the first few lines at least?

Answer (score 1):

When you build a file, it is good to have a build directory, then java will put the class in the correct package layout.

```
mkdir build
javac -d build path/to/source/Files.java
java -cp build package.name.Files
```